# How to make a count down timer in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm looking for the best way to make a countdown timer in Flutter.
I made it this way, but i'm not sure this efficient way to do it, this is my code :

```
class CountDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final int secondsNum;
  CountDown({Key key, @required this.secondsNum}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CountDownState createState() => _CountDownState(secondsNum);
}
class _CountDownState extends State<CountDown> {
  Timer _timer;
  int _start;
  _CountDownState(int start) {
    this._start = start;
    startTimer();
  }
  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        oneSec,
            (Timer timer) => setState(() {
          if (_start < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
          }
        })
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("$_start");
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And then import that file and call it this way: `CountDown(secondsNum: 50)`.
The problem is that I'm going to call `CountDown(secondsNum: 50)` like 10 times in the same screen.

There are a lot of Javascript libraries that can do the same thing for Web, but I didn't find any for Flutter so far. If anyone has an idea about the best way to do this, please post it below. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't u used [CountdownTimer class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/quiver.async/CountdownTimer-class.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter Countdown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610121/flutter-countdown-timer)

Comment: There is a timer app with flutter, you can check it out: https://github.com/pedromassango/xtimer-flutter-app

Comment: @flix how to use that class? i tried to write it but it say undefined class, i don't know what package it belong  to. can you please show me how to use it?