# Flutter: refresh list subtitle every second

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I am making a flutter app, which counts down to events.
What I would need is a way to refresh a ListView's subtitle every second. 
I am storing all of the events in a list, and I have a function, which takes an index as an argument and returns the time remaining to the event at the given index. This function is written in the subtitle of the ListView, and I'd like to update it every second. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/54611581/11427294 helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Countdown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610121/flutter-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StatefulBuilder + DateTime to update it

```
 StatefulBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, setState){
  }
 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!