# Set state of markers when a condition become true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a marker in map that shows the state of a place open or close.
I am using the following method to check every place if it is open or close.

```
bool chekIfIsOpen() {
          var now = DateTime.now();
          int hour = int.parse(now.hour.toString() + mintues);
          if (hour >= horaireOfToDay && hour <= horaireOfToDay)
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }




setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(
              p.geoPoint.longitude.toString()),
          position: point,
          onTap: ,
          icon: status == Status.open
              ? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen)
                  : BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                      BitmapDescriptor.hueRed)));
    });
```

Now my question is, how can I update the state of markers automatically when the var now = DateTime.now.hour() is between the given hours **without further user interaction**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A. Time Comparison

As a human, we always think it will be more `straight-forward` to compare hour value of 2 time windows.

But, actually, for `dart`, it is faster to compare two time windows along with its minutes and seconds.

To get this privilege, we need to convert all timestamp format, which usually comes with `String` type.

We will convert it to DateTime by using this `syntax` :

```dart
    var someTimestamp = "2020-06-19 09:00:00";
    var someDatetimeObject = DateTime.parse(someTimestamp); // 9 a.m.
```

or, if you are new to `dart`, you can make it more intuitive by pairing their `Type`.

In this example below, we will replace `var` which shows dynamic variable, to more static type :

```dart
    String someTimestamp = "2020-06-19 09:00:00";
    DateTime someDatetimeObject = DateTime.parse(someTimestamp); // 9 a.m.
```

In short, I think you will have this part of code :

## A.1 Final Code

```dart
  bool checkIfIsOpen() {
    var horaireOfTodayOpen = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 09:00:00"); // 9 a.m.
    var horaireOfTodayClose = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 17:00:00"); // 5 p.m.
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    if (now.isBefore(horaireOfTodayClose) && now.isAfter(horaireOfTodayOpen)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

## A.2 Detail Explanation Steps

### 1. First you need to have two time window

For example, some organization opens at 9 a.m. and closes at 5 p.m

```dart
    var horaireOfTodayOpen = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 09:00:00"); // 9 a.m.
    var horaireOfTodayClose = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 17:00:00"); // 5 p.m.
```

### 2. Then you need to have current time

Using standard syntax :

```dart
    var now = new DateTime.now();
```

### 3. Lastly, compare it using instance method

You can read it in this official docs [page](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/DateTime-class.html#instance-methods)

```dart
    if (now.isBefore(horaireOfTodayClose) && now.isAfter(horaireOfTodayOpen)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

## B. Periodically Refresh Page / Widget

We need to trigger setState, let say every 5 seconds.

### 1. Make Timer Property and init the with it

```dart
import 'dart:async'; // add this

class MapMarkerPage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer timer; // add this

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 5); // add this
    timer = new Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => refreshMarkers()); // add this
  }

...
}
```

### 2. Loop Through Possible Markers

> Please note, in this section, I will post `PSEUDUCODE` related to markers, because I don't know specifically you solve this.

After we have `refreshMarkers`, in first section, we now know, that it will be executed every 5 seconds.

Now, we need to define its business-logic :

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class MapMarkerPage extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<dynamic> markers = []; // add this

  bool checkIfIsOpen(horaire) {
    var horaireOfTodayOpen = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 09:00:00"); // 9 a.m.
    var horaireOfTodayClose = DateTime.parse("2020-06-19 17:00:00"); // 5 p.m.
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    if (now.isBefore(horaireOfTodayClose) && now.isAfter(horaireOfTodayOpen)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void refreshMarkers() {
    List<Widget> tempMarkers = [];

    // Loop through possible organization
    // Pseudocode
    for (horaire in horaires){  
      if checkIsOpen(horaire){
        tempMarkers.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(
              p.geoPoint.longitude.toString()),
          position: point,
          onTap: ,
          icon: status == Status.open
              ? BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen)
                  : BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                      BitmapDescriptor.hueRed)));
      }
    }

    markers = tempMarkers; // Renew markers 
    setState(() {}); // Force Widget to Update
  }
}
```

I hope you will understand the main idea, the final code may not `100%` applicable to your app, but I hope it will be clearer now

Comment: thanks for you answer , the problem is how to call this function dynamicly, late say i am in the place X time is 1659 so i is open but i still  in the same page a minute  without refrshing so normally the place is been closed , how to change this state

Comment: so without further user interaction, you need to trigger setState periodically ? Is that what you mean ?

Comment: I just updated in addition to Refreshing functionality. You need to see this ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610121/flutter-countdown-timer, and later add dispose method by yourself