# Add timer to every instance of class

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and mobile development and for training I've decided to make a simple plant app that can track when you need to water them.

And I'm stuck with the problem how to implement countdown timer for each instance of class Plant and after display the remaining time. So I need to have this timer also in a background when app is closed.

Comment: Can anyone link me to the correct solution? Thank You all in advance :)

Comment: i hope these help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610121/flutter-countdown-timer and https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPhhEgpyVY8