# is there anything available in flutter to hold or pause a screen Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, timer, pause

[image]

I want to create a custom pause button to hold or pause screen widgets without using game engine can someone help me?

When I click on pause button the timer stop and count stop and animation stop again I click on button all things resume ?

Comment: Can you please give us more details? What do you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to press the pause button to pause the count down, the keyword you are looking for is [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and [Timer.periodic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54611581/14533058).