# How to set remainder countdown by getting values from database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timer

[image]

In this screen I am creating ride, and taking all these information include (Date and Time of ride) from the driver. After creating a ride I am saving all the data into firestore and getting data into next screen. I am also pasting the screenshot of next screen below

[image]

I want to show the countdown according to the date & time and when the countdown end, the start button will enable. how can we do it ? Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get difference of time. Start countdown timer with that time. Once you get zero you can enable start button based on that condition. You can [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54611581/11647876) this solution.