# Flutter: Android AppLock Screens where it can lock phone after reaching certain time and cant open without the passcode or after the restriction time

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm a newbie and I just want to ask if is there a feature in Flutter where it can lock the phone itself, I want to create an Android app where it reaches a certain time it locks the phone and if the user wants to use the phone they should enter a passcode???

**PS:** I am new in flutter and still learning to hope that someone can help me.

Some detailed explanation Thanks...

Comment: Try looking at [Flutter Countdown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610121/flutter-countdown-timer) and [Passcode Lock Screen in Flutter](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/passcode-lock-screen-in-flutter-d97d7e124352).