# Flutter countdown animation with text customization

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Trying to create a simple countdown timer animation in `Flutter`.

I have used the `StepTween` class along with an `AnimatedController` to achieve the animation using the following:

[Flutter - Create a countdown widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302588/flutter-create-a-countdown-widget).

However, what I am trying to accomplish looks something like this:

[image]

I tried creating a `Row` widget and adding a `Text()` followed by `AnimatedWidget()`. However the styling is nowhere near the expected result:

[image]

1. How do I get the size/color for the text within the `AnimatedWidget()` to match the design?
2. The `AnimatedWidget()` switches to a single digit within the 0-10 region. For example instead of showing the countdown as `0:09` it is shown as `0:9`. How do I change that?

Thanks!

Comment: you should ask the author of `Countdown` widget (whatever it is) as it is not a part of public flutter API

Comment: There is no usage of any third party library in this.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/index.html i tried `Countdown` in the "Search API Docs" (upper right corner) but got nothing - only `CountdownTimer`

Comment: My bad. Countdown is my own custom class which extends AnimatedWidget. Shall update the question.

Comment: so you should ask yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In countdown widget

```
 child: new Text(val.toString(), style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 150.0)),
```

is responsible for the styling you see. Instead try removing the style or apply the theme:

```
 child: new Text(val.toString(), style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
```

Comment: Not sure what are you pointing at here. Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: In your original post asked "How do I get the size/color for the text within the AnimatedWidget() to match the design?". If you look at the source code of your custom class which extends AnimatedWidget, that is the part that determines the styling of the counter. If you want a default text style of your app's Theme you can remove the style parameter from the Text widget showing the counter. If you want it changed, then you can do it right there or link from the Theme (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes).

Comment: That fixed the first issue. Any clue about the second query?

Comment: To add a leading zero you can change:

    child: new Text(val.toString()),

to:

    child: new Text(val.toString().padLeft(2, '0')),

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Would you be open to doing a collab on a project if needed?

Comment: Happy to hear that my solution worked for you. I'm staying busy, but may be open to new endeavors. Ping me when you have new ideas.