# Update the duration of TweenAnimationBuilder before the countdown ends

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown

I am trying to add count down widget by using TweenAnimationBuilder, and following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64906353/13240914 but the problem is.. I would like to change the duration.. so for example I have set the duration for 2 minutes and then when user click a button the duration will change into 3 minutes. Is there a way to do that ? I have tried to update the duration by ValueListenableBuilder and showing the remaining countdown inside builder property but the countdown doesn't update from 2 to 3 minutes

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the code is in https://stackoverflow.com/q/70548133/13240914 and that's my peevious question